# tricky telescopic sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum of $\frac{1}{n+a-b}-\frac{1}{n+a}$ from $n=1$ to infinity.

Show that is in fact an finite sum.

I have written down some terms but can't see where cancellation is occurring.

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ natural? what do you mean by 'finite sum' ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you cannot write as telescopic, since you do not have hypothesis on $a,b$.
$$\frac{1}{n+a-b}-\frac1{n+a}=\frac{b}{(n+a-b)(n+a)}, $$
hence
$$\sum \Big(\frac{1}{n+a-b}-\frac1{n+a}\Big)=\sum\frac{b}{(n+a-b)(n+a)},$$
which converges since is comparable with $\sum\frac1{n^2}$...

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong or am I missing something

Comment: @DigitalBrain For it to telescope, you need $b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for correction, I've editd my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $b \in \mathbb Z
$

**Hint:**
$$\frac{1}{n+a-b}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{n+a}}$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1+a-b}-\color{red}{\frac{1}{n+1+a}}$$

$$\frac{1}{n+2+a-b}-\frac{1}{n+2+a}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\frac{1}{n+b+a-b}-\frac{1}{n+b+a}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n+a}}-\frac{1}{n+b+a}$$

$$\frac{1}{n+b+1+a-b}-\frac{1}{n+b+1+a}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n+1+a}}-\frac{1}{n+b+1+a}$$

Comment: $\frac1{n+b+a-b}$ appears only if $n+b$ is integer.

Comment: Thanks for correction, I've edited my answer